# Why is Batman featured more prominently in the poster of Justice League: Doom?

Tags: justice-league-doom

[image: Doom]
In the Box cover art of the movie [Justice League:Doom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2027128/) Batman is featured more prominently compared to the rest of the JLA members (who are on his batarang). Is there a reason why one member is given more prominence over the others? Has this been done before, albeit with other characters given the limelight?

Comment: Because he's Batman. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2027128/) you cited gives this teaser at the top:

> Vandal Savage steals confidential files **Batman** has compiled on the members of the Justice League, and learns all their weaknesses.

And this synopsis:

> The Justice League are a team of great power, but also of personal secrets they thought safe. That changes when the immortal supervillain, Vandal Savage, has **Batman's Batcave secretly raided** to learn them all and more. Soon, the Leaguers are individually beset by their enemies who attack them with inescapable death traps specifically designed with that information. With that, all seems lost until an indomitable Knight and a young Titan combine to deliver salvation even as Savage uses the opportunity to implement a far grander scheme.

It would seem that Batman is the main focus since it was **his** files that were stolen, putting the rest of the team at risk.

Comment: In addition to that it may also be that the publishers wanted to profit from *Batman*'s success, given that he was "hot" at the time.